# How to read the zip file from the drive

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am read the zip file from the google drive in the databricks i am getting an error:

```
Archive:  /tmp/dataset.csv.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/dataset.csv.zip or
        /tmp/dataset.csv.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/dataset.csv.zip.ZIP, period.
tail: cannot open 'dataseta1.csv' for reading: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'dataseta1.csv': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

open your Google Drive

account > New > More > Connect more apps.

Search for ZIP Extractor and install it. Now, you can select any archived file in Google Drive for extraction. Select the file and right-click to Open with the ZIP Extractor for ZIP files stored in Drive